# Is there any difference between PrincipalSearcher and FindByIdentity

Tags: c#

I am looking at active directory solution developed by ex developer, he is using two ways to search for a group.

One is using [`PrincipalSearcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) and another is by adding [`FindByIdentity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359434(v=vs.110).aspx) method to `GroupPrincipalExtension` class (which inherits from `GroupPrincipal`).

I looked at performance wise they both work with same performance.